# both floor and ceiling functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The question I am trying to solve is

$\lfloor x - \lceil \frac{x}{2}\rceil \rfloor =3.$

If anyone could explain/give me advice on how to solve this question, that would be great.

Edited: I initially equated ceiling(x/2) to n/2, n/2<x≤n/2+1, but I do not understand how this could be solved with the presence of another x. Another thing that confuses me is how there is a ceiling function inside of the floor function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't overcomplicated it. A floor and ceil are just things that modify their arguments.

$\lfloor y\rfloor = k$ is just a all the reals $k \leq y < k+1$. This is by definition!

It's just a short hand notation.

So use your expression for y and k:

$3 \leq x - \lceil \frac{x}{2} \rceil < 4$

So you have to find an x value that when you subtract around half from it gives you something between 3 and 4.

e.g., what if $x = 6$? Then

$3 \leq 6 - \lceil \frac{6}{2}\rceil = 6 - 3 = 3 < 4$

So $x = 6$ works. What about x = 8?

$3 \leq 8 - \lceil \frac{8}{2}\rceil = 8 - 4 = 4 < 4$

and $x = 8$ almost works.

$3 \leq x - \left(\frac{x}{2} - \epsilon\right) < 4$

We can replace the floor or ceil with a compensation factor because, say $\lceil 4.3 \rceil = 5 = 5.3 - .7$. Here $\epsilon = 0.7$.

$3 \leq \frac{x}{2} + \epsilon < 4$

$6 - 2\epsilon \leq x  < 8 - 2\epsilon$

Now $0 < \epsilon < 1$

$6 - 2\epsilon \leq x  < 8 - 2\epsilon$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand it now!

Comment: @0o1hnk Just work through them slow until you get a feel. A floor just returns the "lower integer" of a real(3.4 -> 3, 49384.4324 -> 49384). A ceil returns the "upper integer". Hence if you are trying to "reverse" this and find the values that give an integer then you will have a lot of possibilities: 3.4->3, 3.3->3, 3.2343234->3, 3.999999-3. The $\epsilon$ helps track them all. It doesn't matter if you have a very complex function of floors and ceilings, still same basic idea but just more stuff to deal with.